# how to set background color of image element in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have created image element dynamically. I want to set background color of the image element. it is not working for the following code.

```
var img = $('<img />', {
                id: 'img1',
                src: '/ProductImages/' + products[1].PictureFileName
            }).appendTo(span);
            img.width(150); img.height(200);
            img.css('background-color', '#efeeef');
            img.className = 'bkcolor';
```

Comment: Your first statement has no sense! Please add HTML code to help us give you an answer.

Comment: I created am image item by using an id and image file. The image is displaying in a division. But I am unable to change its background color which I need.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: I misread your first statement, and I must withdraw "has no sense"! On the other hand, I don't know if it totally solve your problem but at least you _must_ use `img.addClass()` instead of `img.className`, as stated by @juporag.

Answer (score 2):

Does your `img` `src` point to a transparent image? I created a codepen using the Google image, and it seems to work. [Check it out here](http://codepen.io/longmatthewh/pen/gPRbRq).

Comment: I verified your answer. thank you for reply. but what may be the reason for not working in my project. I am working with visual studio 2013.

Comment: Is your image transparent? Could you point to one of your example images in the codepen, or attach it here?

Answer (score 1):

The className property does not exist in jQuery.

Try with img.addClass('bkcolor')

```
var img = $('<img />', {
                id: 'img1',
                src: '/ProductImages/' 
            }).appendTo(span);
            img.width(150); img.height(200);
            img.css('background-color', '#efeeef');
            img.addClass('bkcolor')
```

Comment: my image was padded with white color, due to which it was not working.